# How to import qemu project to Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, ide, eclipse-cdt, qemu

I want to import qemu project [version 2.9.0](http://download.qemu-project.org/qemu-2.9.0.tar.xz) to Eclipse CDT (NEON) for modify the code. I used to import it as an Autotools project but it has a lot of missing define tag and header file that preprocessor cannot find. Are there any tutorials or explanation about that. thanks

Or should I change to the another IDE?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

- Run the configure script from a terminal
- Assuming that generates a makefile, Build the project from Eclipse. This will invoke "make all" (you can adjust the target name in the project settings if necessary).

CDT has a "build output parser" that will parse the build commands contained in the make output, and configure your project's includes and defines accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

qemu doesn't use autotools (the configure script is hand-written not autoconf-generated).